# Slow Web Performance on two Windows 2008 R2 Terminal Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server

We have two Windows 2008 R2 servers that we use for agents to log into to access our customers systems.  Saturday morning we received complaints that on both servers the web is running horribly slow.  This happens on all websites and the majority of the time the web site times out trying to load.

Other users located at the same site but using their desktop machine do not see any issue.  We have rebooted the boxes and checked settings and cannot find the cause.  The CPU/Memory/Network/Disk Space use on the server is very low.  I thought it might have been a MS update causing the issue but it appears the last update was applied in January.

We have rebooted both boxes and I am in process of trying a different browser.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: I installed FireFox and it didn't make any difference.  When I tried to download FireFox on the server it was downloading at between 500bytes and 1kb.  We have also switched to a different network port and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: It appears it might be a network issue.  I have the same problem with the other servers but no issues with the desktop's.

Comment: Are you running the 2008 boxes on vmware or hyper-v? Or are they stand alone systems with separate nic's? Are using remote desktop into the system after VPN connection or other way? What else sits in front of these boxes before it hits the internet?

Comment: *  One of the boxes is running on top of a Hyper-V box, but right now it is the only host running on the box.  The only server is a stand alone box.  *  We are remoting into the server using RDP through a Juniper SSL VPN connection.  We have tried on the local box and get the same problem.  *  There is a couple switches and a few routers and firewalls.

Comment: is it random on a particular site?  In otherwords if you F5 several times on a page that isn't loading does it eventually work, or is it always down?

Comment: To clarify, other applications are responsive, only web browsing is slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you RDP into servers and run Network Monitor while trying to browse the slow sites and see if you get retransmits, syn retransmits, etc.

Also narrow your issue by trying non HTTP protocols out to Internet and see if it's just web browsing.

If your using a web proxy that would be a place to troubleshoot as well.

Comment: It turns out it was the web proxy.  Strange how it would only affect the users on the terminal server.  After a reboot of the proxy server everything started to work proper.